# Xamarin.Forms ошибка "Свойство Content установлено больше одного раза"

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Хочу оставить таблицу, но при этом не пользоваться переключателем "Save"

```
<SwitchCell Text="Save" />
```

, а добавить кнопку.  Вот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tree"
         x:Class="Tree.MainPage"
         Title="Geneological Tree">

<!--<ContentView Padding="40">
     Place new controls here 
    <Button
        x:Name="bSignUp" 
        Text="SIGN UP"
        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Clicked="OnButtonClicked"
        TextColor="White"
        FontSize="Medium"
        BackgroundColor="LightSeaGreen"/>

</ContentView>-->

<TableView>
    <TableView.Root>
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="Personal information">
                <EntryCell Label="Name:" Keyboard="Default" Placeholder="enter your name" />
                <EntryCell Label="Surname:" Keyboard="Default" Placeholder="enter your surname" />
                <EntryCell Label="Sex:" Keyboard="Default" Placeholder="enter your sex" />
                <EntryCell Label="Birthday:" Keyboard="Default" Placeholder="enter your birthday" />
                <SwitchCell Text="Save" />
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView.Root>
</TableView>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2):

В ConteтеPage может быть только один элемент. Вы пытаетесь разместить два. Необходимо их собрать в какой-нибудь контейнер. Например, в Grid. Задаете в нем две строки и указываете, что TableView будет находится во второй. Вот так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tree"
         x:Class="Tree.MainPage"
         Title="Geneological Tree">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentView Padding="40">  
            <Button
            x:Name="bSignUp" 
            Text="SIGN UP"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Clicked="OnButtonClicked"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="Medium"
            BackgroundColor="LightSeaGreen"/>

        </ContentView>

        <TableView Grid.Row="1">
            <TableView.Root>
                <TableRoot>
                    <TableSection Title="Personal information">
                        <EntryCell Label="Name:" Keyboard="Default" Placeholder="enter your name" />
                        <EntryCell Label="Surname:" Keyboard="Default" Placeholder="enter your surname" />
                        <EntryCell Label="Sex:" Keyboard="Default" Placeholder="enter your sex" />
                        <EntryCell Label="Birthday:" Keyboard="Default" Placeholder="enter your birthday" />
                        <SwitchCell Text="Save" />
                    </TableSection>
                </TableRoot>
            </TableView.Root>
        </TableView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Исправило, но кнопки все равно не видно

Comment: Вы точно вот так прописали: <TableView Grid.Row="1">

Comment: Да, уже решил проблему. Оказалось, что Table view автоматически заменяет всё пространство => кнопки не было видно. Просто добавил вместо tableview парочку enter-ов.